# Forms Authentication on browser exit

Tags: asp.net, .net, authentication, asp.net-mvc-4

This morning me and my co-worker went on discussion about storing auth cookie when
RememberMe = false.

MVC4 , Forms Authentocation, C#.Net, Visual Studio 2012, IIS 7.5 , InProcess Session

1. User LogsIn,(RememberMe = false) and Navigates to an item in the app.Default session      timeOut was set 30 mins,
2. User Copied the URL and Closed the browser(IE9)
3. Opened new browser(IE9) and Pasted the Copied URL, UI redirected to loginPage.

Here I say session created in step 1 is still valid., On close of the browser , browser lost the AuthCookie.

He says that that Session is created based on browser session also. I'm bit confused.

Please let me know what actually happened.

Sorry for the bad English

Answer (score 3):

RememberMe = false means the authentication cookie that was issued to the user was NOT persistent (the expiration of the cookie is set to "SESSION").  That is, the cookie is lost when the browser session ends.  RememberMe = true means a persistent cookie is created and is saved across multiple browser sessions(the expiration of the cookie is set to a specific date, usually configured in web.config).

Read the [documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b.aspx)

Comment: If I close the Browser, How the server will know to end/kill the session stored in server,HTTP is stateless.

Comment: the information to kill the cookie is stored in the cookie on the browser, not HTTP.

Comment: @Nash Kiwi is correct. The expiration property of the cookie (stored in the cookie itself) is set to "session" which means when the session ends (ie the browser is closed) the cookie will be destroyed.

Comment: @Forty-Two, I agree from the browser point of view,Cookie in the Browser will be killed. But what about the Session created in Web Server ? You mean to say, on Close of Browser, the Session created in Web Server also get killed before reaching its expiration time.

Comment: @Nash There is no session on server side in mvc unless you create and manage it yourself.

Comment: @Forty-Two, I'm more confused now. In Forms Authentication, I'm assuming After User Credentials are verified and logged-In successfully a session generated as SessionID and this ID is stored in browser cookie and exists in WebServer also with Expiration Time based on settings. Right ?

Comment: @Nash No that's not correct.  Forms Authentication and Session State use two different cookies.  In other words one has nothing to do with the other unless you couple them.

Comment: You also seem to be mixing up HTTP session with ASP.NET SessionState.

Comment: @Forty-Two,Sorry for the confusion. Though I didn't specify about ASP.Net Session or HTTP session, Forms Authentication has nothing to do with ASP.Net Session, please find the reply from KeyboardP, below. Could you please answer about HTTP Session ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using the default [Session-State Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which is InProc. A session generates a [SessionID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.sessionid%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and this ID is stored in a cookie. This cookie is sent to the user and whilst requests are made with that cookie, the session is alive. The ID itself identifies the unique browser, which is why you can log into the same website with different accounts when you use two different browsers at the same time. However, you can't sign into different accounts from different tabs of the same browser (unless the website has specifically customised their site to support that feature).

By closing the browser, this cookie is deleted, and so the session will be ended when its timeout period has been reached. The reason you're taken to the UI page is because the new cookie you have no longer has the same session ID so, for all intents and purposes, you're a new user.

Comment: But, still the Session is valid at the server right ? It will expired on its expiration time, based on settings. If I hack the session from the browser I can still communicate  with server. Also if get the session ID and pass it over new type of browser say Chrome..Can I communicate with the server? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, I think that's correct. The session still exists on the server until the timeout period is reached. Also, if you force a different browser to send the same cookie, the session should continue (although you may still need to log in again in the new browser). I haven't tried this, so someone else might be able to confirm or correct  me.